# Trade-off between defining a BIND list inside my model class, and the ability to edit the object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Currently on the model class level I have excluded from the model binder any attributes that should not be defined by  users, such as CreatedDate or any navigation properties objects.

So inside my model class I define the following `BIND` list. This will not allow a user (or even a hacker) to include a value for the CreatedDate field, and this value will only be set inside the system code, when the object is created. So I did not include it in the Bind list as follow:-

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Group_validation))]
    [Bind(Include="Description,GroupID,Name")]
    public partial class Group
    {
```

But the problem is that inside the POST Edit action method, I have the following code:-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Group group)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    groupRepository.InsertOrUpdate(group);
                    groupRepository.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();

                var clientValues = (Group)entry.Entity;
```

And this will raise an error since CreateDate field is required, and I am excluding it from the model binder? So how I can exclude the CreateDate from the model binder, but at the same time to avoid the null exception?

I know that I can just pass the objectID to the Edit action method, but this will prevent the DbUpdateConcurrencyException from being fired. so I had to pass the Group object to the edit action method , as I am doing in the above code.

Comment: May be CreateDate isn't DbNull. Did you check this?

Comment: yes CreateDate is not null on the database,, and it should be like this.